# Difference between Normalization and Partitioning in DBMS

Tags: database, oracle, rdbms, database-normalization

Is there any difference between the term 'Normalization' and 'Partitioning' used in Database management system? I tried google it but couldn't find a proper answer in simple words. Also what is the difference between Horizontal and Vertical Partitioning?

Comment: 2 **total** different things

Comment: Normalization is to properly define the relations between the **TABLES**. Partitioning is another concept where we split the database tables into individual smaller tables (behind which reason is that: **less data to be searched leads to less retrieval time** )

Answer (score 8):

[Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) involves designing the tables in the database to reduce or eliminate duplicated data. Normalization is a **logical database design** issue.

[Horizontal partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(database)#Partitioning_methods) is the process of breaking a large monolithic table into a series of smaller subtables which can be queried faster and managed more effectively by the DBMS. (This is what most people mean when they talk about "partitioning").

[Vertical partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(database)#Partitioning_methods) is the process of using multiple tables to store the data for a single entity; thus, instead of a single table with 100 columns you might have 4 tables with 25 columns each. Reasons for vertical partitioning might include storing large columns (e.g. BLOBs) or infrequently used columns on inexpensive-but-slow storage devices, while storing more-frequently-accessed columns on faster-but-more-expensive storage devices.

Partitioning is a **physical database design** issue.

Answer (score 0):

To your first question yes they are completely different concepts.
Normalisation is the process where-by you remove repeated data and store it in referential tables.
[Normalisation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Partitioning reefers to the actual physical storage of the data on disk.

I could reword it but [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178148(v=sql.105).aspx) puts it simply enough.